# c++ vector indexing by another vector

Tags: c++, vector, indexing

sry for asking this obviously easy question but I was unable to find the exact answer for my issue and I'm obviously to inexperienced to derive the answer form similar problems...

Suppose I have the following situation

```
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Test" << std::endl;

    int myints1[] = {1, 1 , 0, 0};
    std::vector<int> vec1 (myints1, myints1 + sizeof(myints) / sizeof(int) );
    int myints2[] = {1, 2 , 3, 4};
    std::vector<int> vec2 (myints, myints2 + sizeof(myints2) / sizeof(int) );

    std::vector<int> resultVec;

    // Now as a result I want to get the resultVec as all entries in vec2 
    // where vec1 == 0, resulting in resultVec = [3,4]
    return 0

}
```

How to select all entries of one vector by the value of another vector?

Comment: not really clear what is the problem. write a loop check the condition if it is met push the entry from vec2 to resultVec. Do you know how to iterate all elements in a vector?

Comment: Yes, but if I iterate through vec1 like 'for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = vec1.begin(); it != vec1.end(); ++it)' I only have access to vec1, and if I iterate through vec2 I only have access to vec2 or do I miss something?

Comment: @HolgerBarlt No, you have access to both vectors. But it will be easier to use an index counter rather than an iterator.

Comment: The purpose of iterators is that you dont need to care about indices, if you do care about indices dont use iterators. Please dont put code in comments, better include it in the question (maybe together with error messages and/or the code that you would like to write but you cannot)

Comment: Or zip them: `boost::combine`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can have a loop that increments two iterators. Because your collections are the same type you can decalre both in the for, and because they are the same size, you only need to check one.

```
for (auto it1 = vec1.begin(), it2 = vec2.begin(); it1 != vec1.end(); ++it1, ++it2) 
{
     // Use *it1 and *it2
}
```

If you have access to C++17 and boost, you can use a nice ranged-for

```
for (auto & [val1, val2] : boost::combine(vec1, vec2))
{
     // Use val1 and val2
}
```

Note that you can use `{}` to initialise `vector`s, so I wouldn't bother with `myints`.

```
std::vector<int> vec1 = {1, 1, 0, 0};
std::vector<int> vec2 = {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

Answer (score 6):

Just looping on the index should do the trick here. This code assumes that `vec2`s size is at least as big as `vec1`.

```
int main() {
    std::cout << "Test" << std::endl;

    int myints1[] = {1, 1 , 0, 0};
    std::vector<int> vec1 (myints1, myints1 + sizeof(myints) / sizeof(int) );
    int myints2[] = {1, 2 , 3, 4};
    std::vector<int> vec2 (myints, myints2 + sizeof(myints2) / sizeof(int) );

    std::vector<int> resultVec;

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < vec1.size(); ++i) {
        if (!vec1[i]) resultVec.push_back(vec2[i]);
    }
    return 0

}
```